# Is it good practice to change certain page appearance through a widget?

Tags: widgets

If I want to use a same widget but when the post page type different, I would like to show header and footer in different style. Can I change the appearance through the widget? If it's not a good way, what is the best way to do it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it is not good practice to use a widget to change appearance of other items than the widget itself.

If you want to influence the appearance for a specific post type, you can work with [post templates](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Type_Templates).

> archive-{post_type}.php
>      single-{post_type}.php

If such a template file is in use, there is also a class added to the body element `single-{post_type}`. You can then refer to this class in CSS:

```
.single-post_type .footer {

}
```

If you really just want to change the appearance for one specific page, just use the post-id or page-id which are added to the body element's class:

```
.postid-## .footer {

}

.page-id-## .footer {

}
```